# Using Mapsforge and ABS library from a single activity

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, openstreetmap

I have been using Action Bar Sherlock in my Application and using ABS requires me to extend `SherlockActivity`. Now I want to use Mapsforge(A library for rendering offline vector maps using OpenStreetMap data) which means I need to extend `mapactivity` but I also need ABS at the same time.

Is there any workaround for this?